# Optional fields Grok pattern LOGSATSH

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, grok

I am working with grok to parse my logs in logstash, and there is a lot of difference between my logs (optional fields), I would like to know which solution is the best and why!

1- Make one complicated filter with a lot of optional fields

2- Make a filter for each log

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's probably best to bring some example that illustrates the issue you're facing.

Comment: You can combine both, try to group them by similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined between the both and it's working perfectly

Thanks for your help